# how to pass value of textbox to another textbox in a modal using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox in my page, what I want is to do some sort of "preview" using a modal, but i cannot display the value of textbox which I put the information i need. Can someone help me?

I use javascript in doing this, but my modal displays empty textbox.

```
$('#<%= txtDetails.ClientID %>').on('change', function () {
   $('input[id$="txtKBDecription"]').text($(this).val()); 
}); 
$('#<%= txtIssue.ClientID %>').on('keyup', function () {
   $('input[id$="txtKBSummary"]').text($(this).val()); 
}); 
$('#<%= area.ClientID %>').on('change', function () {
   $('input[id$="txtKBResolution"]').text($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: show us your code man. it would make things easier to show us where you are stuck at the moment

Comment: Is your modal a custom modal using a `div` or some other element within the same document, or a real modal created by `showModalDialog()`, or something else?

Comment: $('#<%= txtDetails.ClientID %>').on('change', function () {
                $('input[id$="txtKBDecription"]').text($(this).val());
            });

            $('#<%= txtIssue.ClientID %>').on('keyup', function () {
                $('input[id$="txtKBSummary"]').text($(this).val());
            });

            $('#<%= area.ClientID %>').on('change', function () {
                $('input[id$="txtKBResolution"]').text($(this).val());
            });

Comment: txtKBDecription is the textbox in my modal, but is just shows an empty textbox

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at angularjs!

Answer (score 2):

Really need more specifics, but essentially you're going to grab the value form one and put it in the other whenver it changes.

this goes in your preview modal

```
<input type="text" id="preview" onchange="Copy();">
```

and this one goes in your final modal

```
<input type="text" id="final">
```

and code...

```
<script>
function Copy()
{
    document.getElementById("final").value = document.getElementById("preview").value;
}
</script>
```

though it should really be something closer to

```
<script>
function Copy()
{
    var previewValue = document.getElementById("preview").value;
    if(previewValue != "" /* Or Other Validation */)
         document.getElementById("final").value = previewValue;
}
</script>
```

you should also consider checking to make sure the elements exist if you are planning on having other people edit the page and/or to make it more robust.